# Complexity of grouping in Java8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, time-complexity, collectors

I would like to learn the time complexity of the given statement below.(In Java8)

```
list.stream().collect(groupingBy(...));
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no general answer to that question, as the time complexity depends on all operations. Since the stream has to be processed entirely, there is a base time complexity of `O(n)` that has to be multiplied by the costs of all operations done per element. This, assuming that the iteration costs itself are not worse than `O(n)`, which is the case for most stream sources.

So, assuming no intermediate operations that affect the time complexity, the `groupingBy` has to evaluate the function for each element, which should be independent of other elements, so not affect the time complexity (regardless of how expensive it is, as the `O(…)` time complexity only tells us, how the time *scales* with large numbers of stream elements). Then, it will insert the element into a map, which might depend on the number of already contained elements. Without a custom `Map` supplier, the map’s type is unspecified, hence, no statement can be made here.

In practice, it’s reasonable to assume that the result will be some sort of hashing map with a net `O(1)` lookup complexity by default. So we have a net time complexity of `O(n)` for the grouping. Then, we have the *downstream* collector.

The default *downstream* collector is `toList()`, which produces an unspecified `List` type, so again, we can’t say anything about the costs of adding elements to it.

The current implementation produces an `ArrayList`, which has to perform copy operations when the capacity is exceeded, but since the capacity is raised by a *factor* each time, there is still a net complexity of `O(n)` for adding *n* elements. It’s reasonable to assume that future changes to the `toList()` implementation won’t make the costs worse than what we have today. So the time complexity of a default `groupingBy` collection is likely `O(n)`.

If we use a custom `Map` collector with a custom downstream collector, the complexity depends on the average number of groups to number of elements per group ratio. The worst case would be the worst of either, the map’s lookup and the downstream collector’s element processing (times the number of elements), as we could have one group containing all items or each item being in its own group.

But usually, you are capable of predicting a bias for a particular grouping operation, so you would want to calculate a time complexity for that particular operation, instead of relying on a statement about all grouping operations in general.

Comment: yes it seems to be 0(n) for grouping by getter of some object, <100ms for 100k records pretty fast