# Java Program getting failed with timeout for some test cases

Tags: java, performance, collections, java-8

I was practising on Hackerrank. Well, the question is pretty much simple I have attached it over here with sample input. When I run into my local machine with custom input its working as expected. But while I am running on its online platform sometime 2 and sometimes 3 test cases getting failed with time out exception. Code is below here anyone can suggest what improvement is needed?

[image]

This is the solution

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int k = 3;
        List<Integer> marks = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        marks.add(20);
        marks.add(20);
        marks.add(40);
        marks.add(60);
        marks.add(20);
        marks.add(10);
        marks.add(0);
        marks.add(100);
        System.out.println(numofPrizes(k, marks));
    }
    public static int numofPrizes(int k, List<Integer> list) {
        // Write your code here
        Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());
        List<Integer> str = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        AtomicInteger rank = new AtomicInteger(0);
        AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
        list.stream().forEach(x -> {
            if(!str.contains(x)){
                rank.getAndIncrement();
            }
            if(rank.get() <= k && x > 0){
                count.getAndIncrement();
            }
            str.add(x);
//          System.out.println("mark " + x + " rank " + rank.get() + " count " + count.get() );
        });
        return count.get();     
    }
```

Output :

```
mark 100 rank 1 count 1
mark 60 rank 2 count 2
mark 40 rank 3 count 3
mark 20 rank 4 count 3
mark 20 rank 4 count 3
mark 20 rank 4 count 3
mark 10 rank 5 count 3
mark 0 rank 6 count 3
3
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the problem, but shouldn't the result be equal to `k` or the number of marks (if the array size is less than k) itself, excluding the people with marks equal to `0`?

Comment: Yes, Naman, that's correct, See above I have updated with output.

Comment: Well, I believe I did misunderstand the question, instead of a number to cut off, I think `k` means the cut-off rank and then evaluate the number of people who would get rewarded. In which case, with your same input, if `k=4`, the result would be 6. Am I right?

Comment: yes thats correct

Comment: As stated in the answers, you're losing time with needless sorting and even more by slow contains. I'd add that you're misusing streams for thing which can be done faster and  much simpler using ordinary loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I just change the approach as below, It got worked.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int k = 3;
    List<Integer> marks = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    marks.add(20);
    marks.add(20);
    marks.add(40);
    marks.add(60);
    marks.add(20);
    marks.add(10);
    marks.add(0);
    marks.add(100);
    System.out.println(numofPrizes(k, marks));
}
public static int numofPrizes(int k, List<Integer> list) {
              list.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());
      int number = 0,counter = 1;
      int[] mark = new int[list.size()],rank = new int[list.size()];
      Map<Integer,Integer> map  = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();   
      for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
              map.put(list.get(i), (map.get(list.get(i)) != null) ? map.get(list.get(i)) : counter);
              mark[i] = list.get(i);
              rank[i] = (int) map.get(list.get(i));
              counter++;
              if(mark[i] > 0 && k >= rank[i]){
                      number++;
              }
      }          
      return number;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Certain parts of the code that you can improve possibly in terms of readability and performance could be:

- you can use `List.sort` for the precise use of the API over elements of a `List`

  ```
  list.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());
  ```
- there is a costly method invocation involved in your code, which is generally an **O(n<sup>2</sup>)** operation and i.e.

  ```
  if(!str.contains(x))
  ```

  this operation could be efficient i.e. **O(n)** when performed over a `HashSet` but then you can also optimize slightly on the additional `add` overhead as:

  ```
  Set<Integer> str = new HashSet<>();

  if (str.add(x)) {
      rank++; // or the use of getAndIncrement
  }
  ```
- at the functional programming construct, you could rather think of `counting` the value while you sort them in reverse order and then limiting to the rank cut-off in the input while performing the sum of the corresponding counts

  ```
  private static int numofPrizes(int k, List<Integer> list) {
      Map<Integer, Integer> valueToCount = list.stream()
              .filter(mark -> mark != 0)
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                      Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.counting(), Long::intValue)));

      return valueToCount.entrySet().stream()
              .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
              .limit(k)
              .mapToInt(Map.Entry::getValue)
              .sum();
  }
  ```

  do note, that the [`groupingBy` here is an **O(n)** operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40823293/complexity-of-grouping-in-java8) again and this complete logic could me merge into a single pipeline as follows:

---

```
private static long numOfPrizes(int k, List<Integer> list) {
    return list.stream()
            .filter(mark -> mark != 0)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
            .limit(k)
            .mapToLong(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .sum();
}
```

Comment: Note: Don't just try and use the final code posted here. I haven't tested its efficiency against the runtime you've been working with. Do note there is a suggestion to optimize what you possibly can in the current code. On the other side of it, do think if there could be something better than the current approach in the first place.

Comment: Appreciated notes and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It can also be thought in this sense that  if the input can be  big in terms of size of input array/list, we should avoid performing sort on it if possible.

Here, since there can be only 100 uniques values for marks, we can use that fact and make a sorted map of Marks to number of occurrence. This will take O(n) time.
or O(n log n) time to sort the map (only 100 entries max)

Key is to avoid sorting large datasets and creating new large datasets by copying larger ones.

Comment: There's no need for a map in your clever solution, an array of length 101 would do for this histogram. A single pass over the input to fill it and a single pass over the histogram to get the answer.

Comment: Using an array would be even better. no of occurrence of marks 56 will be stored in the  57th element of the array( index = 56). Saving even more efforts.