# simplify java stream to find duplicate properties

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `users` list and I want to find all users having duplicate names:

```
var allNames = users
              .stream()
              .map(u -> u.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());

var duplicateNames = allNames
                .stream()
                .filter(i -> Collections.frequency(allNames, i) > 1)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Can I improve/simplify the above solution?

For example, actually I create a list with all names and then filter it. How can I traverse the list to find its duplicate names without creating the additional list `allNames`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution is

```
var duplicate = users.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getName, u -> false, (x,y) -> true))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .filter(Map.Entry::getValue)
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

This creates an intermediate `Map<String,Boolean>` to record which name is occurring more than once. You could use the `keySet()` of that map instead of collecting to a new `Set`:

```
var duplicate = users.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.toMap(User::getName, u -> false, (x,y) -> true, HashMap::new),
            m -> {
                m.values().removeIf(dup -> !dup);
                return m.keySet();
            }));
```

A loop solution can be much simpler:

```
HashSet<String> seen = new HashSet<>(), duplicate = new HashSet<>();
for(User u: users)
    if(!seen.add(u.getName())) duplicate.add(u.getName());
```

Comment: Moreover, the iterative approach passes over the collection only once.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala technically, the stream solutions pass over the source collection only once too. The second iteration will be over the map, which might already contain fewer elements than the original collection, as it only contains unique keys. But yes, that’s still more overhead than the single loop.

Comment: I find the loop-solution easier to read with less code. And the loop-solution does have less overhead in compare to the streams-solution. So I stick with the loop-solution. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah two passes, one over the source collection and the other over the intermediate result. The iterative approach should outperform the streams one. It is more succinct and readable too imo.

Answer (score 2):

Group by the names, find entries with more than one value:

```
Map<String, List<User>> grouped = users.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(User::getName));

List<User> duplicated =
    grouped.values().stream()
        .filter(v -> v.size() > 1)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(toList());
```

(You can do this in a single expression if you want. I only separated the steps to make it a little more clear what is happening).

Note that this does not preserve the order of the users from the original list.

Comment: The OP only wants the names, so you don’t need to group into `List<User>`, a `groupingBy(User::getName, counting())`, followed by collecting a filtered `keySet()` would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution with the help of @holger:

```
// collect all duplicate names with O(n)
var duplicateNames = all.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Strategy::getName, Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(m -> m.getValue() > 1)
                .map(m -> m.getKey())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is the performance of this solution O(n^2) or O(n)?

If someone can find improvements then please share.

Comment: Nit: you have a Set in your original code, a List here.

Comment: The complexity is O(n) in typical implementations, see [Complexity of grouping in Java8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40823293/2711488). You can even simplify the counting to only keep a `boolean` denoting whether it is a duplicate, as in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61011871/2711488).

Comment: @AndyTurner does this matter? The `duplicateNames` is only a `List` containing duplicate names if any. It can also be a `Set`, but the end result should be the same because I already had a map with unique keys before by `Collectors.groupingBy(Strategy::getName, Collectors.counting()))`.